# Erlang.mk project as rebar3 dependency

Tags: erlang, rebar3

I am working on an `amqp1.0 client` for an Erlang [rebar3](https://rebar3.readme.io/)-based project.

I need to add the [`rabbitmq-amqp1.0-client`](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-amqp1.0-client) as the queueing dependency. However, [`rabbitmq-amqp1.0-client`](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-amqp1.0-client) is an [Erlang.mk](https://erlang.mk/) project and cannot simply be added as a dependency since the two build systems are not compatible with each other.

Basically, how do I add the above mentioned `amqp1.0` dependency to my [rebar3](https://rebar3.readme.io/) project?

My previous attempt at this problem was in conjunction with one @DenysGonchar. See the question we asked on rebar3.org forum. As a quick fix, we ended up precompiling the `.beam` files and emptying `src/` contents, then pulling the precompiled deps into the [rebar3](https://rebar3.readme.io/) project. However, this means I have no access to the source files and this makes coding and debugging related code a bother.

> NOTE: No code samples since the project is under NDA.

Answer (score 0):

For anything above 3.0.2 of `amqp_client` you can fetch from [Hex](https://hex.pm/packages/amqp_client) by adding `{amqp_client, "3.8.1"}` to your list of deps.